# Best practices for internationalization using PyQt4

Tags: internationalization, python-3.x, pyqt4

I want to add multiple language support to my application which is written in Python using PyQt4. I was looking for information on how to add multiple languages and would like to see how other people do this.

[Here](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/static/Docs/PyQt4/html/i18n.html) i read:

> The PyQt behaviour is unsatisfactory and may be changed in the future.
>   It is recommended that QCoreApplication.translate() be used in
>   preference to tr() (and trUtf8()). This is guaranteed to work with
>   current and future versions of PyQt and makes it much easier to share
>   message files between Python and C++ code.

In files generated by `pyuic4` i see something like:

```
WPopupCalendar.setWindowTitle(QtGui.QApplication.translate("WPopupCalendar", "Календарь", None, QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8))
```

This looks too long for me. I was thinking to make my own `tr` helper function which somehow would automate the process.

Also i could not find articles describing a workflow and specifics for developing multilingual apps in python with pyqt4.

Would you please advice me with some good and convenient techniques on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `tr` (or `trUtf8`) everywhere to start with. Only bother with `translate` when you identify code that is affected by the issue with multiple inheritance (which could easily be never).

I would suggest you have a look at Qt's [i18n overview](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/internationalization.html), and the [Qt Linguist Manual](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/linguist-manual.html). They are obviously both oriented towards C++ projects, but it should give you a pretty clear idea of what's required.

For a working example, you could also download the source code of the [Eric Python IDE](http://eric-ide.python-projects.org/index.html) - it's written in PyQt4, and has support for a half dozen or more languages.